# UITableView Height does not fit container vertically (bottom) for different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UITableView that in one of my Views. I have been testing the app on an iPhone 4S and it has been working great. Now I tried testing it on an iPhone 5S (which has a taller screen). The UITableView is not fitting to the bottom. I know this has to do with Auto Layout But I am not sure how to set that up.

The two approaches that come to my mind are:

1-) Programmatically determine height of screen and then programmatically setting the UITableView Height to Fit screen
2-) Using Auto-Layout in the Interface Builder. But I get warnings that AutoLayout only works for iOS 8 and higher. So how would I implement that for lower versions of iOS?

So my question is: **How to set the height of a UITableView dynamically so that it fits to the bottom of the screen regardless of the height of the iPhone screen?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Autolayout is available from iOS 6 onwards. Hardcoding a size for the screen is a terrible idea as it will not be portable between different device screen sizes (iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+ and the various iPads). Use autolayout.

Comment: Okay Thanks I will look into it. Do you recommend a tutorial for it?

Comment: Hmmm...personally I've just watched the free WWDC videos (each WWDC since 2012 has had some sort of auto layout video) but I've never followed a tutorial. I know auto layout is also covered in "Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad" in iTunesU and there's also a Ray Wenderlich tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1). Just be aware that there have been some minor changes to enhance autolayout during iOS 7 and in iOS 8. Check the WWDC 2014 videos on laying out a UI first due to the large iOS 8 storyboard changes.

Comment: Awesome thanks. One more question: How would I use auto layout in this specific case? would I add a constraint from the tableview to the view container's bottom so that it stretches depending on the device? thanks

Comment: You would attach constraints to the left, right, bottom and top of the TableView to the SuperView usually with a margin of 0. This will tell the TableView to take up as much space as possible in it's SuperView. Also remember to tell the project that you support the larger size screens by having the appropriate launch images set.

Answer (score 0):

You can set different tableview for different screen size like this.
This define in header of the .m file

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

This is define in viewDidLoad() method

```
 if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 568)];
}else{
        // define for 3.5 inch screen
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
}
```

I hope this should help..

Comment: This will not set the correct size for iPhone 6, iPhone 6+ and all the iPads. Use autolayout instead.

Comment: I feel obliged to remove this as the correct answer. As @RoboticCat mentioned. Hard Coding these things does not seem logical when we can use auto layout. Thanks for the effort though.